# Modifying the port of a URI

Tags: java

In Java, the `URI` class is immutable.

Here's how I'm currently modifying the port:

```
public URI uriWithPort(URI uri, int port) {
    try {
        return new URI(uri.getScheme(), uri.getUserInfo(), uri.getHost(), port,
                       uri.getPath(), uri.getQuery(), uri.getFragment());
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        LOG.error("Updating URI port failed:",e);
        return uri;
    }
}
```

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Nitpicking here: The name of your method might be a bit confusing. It sounds like you will change the port of the passed URI, while it will return a new instance (where you changed the port). So, keep in mind you have to re-assign the URI.

Comment: @Martijn - Valid point.  However, will probably solve it via some javaDocs, as the alternative name (createUriWithPort) feels somewhat clumsy

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux, for immutable objects, the naming `withXXX` has settled for copy methods that return a copy with only `XXX` changed, e.g. https://immutables.github.io/immutable.html#copy-methods

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that's pretty much it. 'Tis a bit verbose, granted, but it's not *that* complicated. :-)

If you're using Java EE rather than just the JDK, see [Talha Ahmed Khan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6490088/157247), which uses Java EE's [`UriBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html), which is still a one-liner but more elegant. That's not part of the JDK, but if you're doing a servlet or similar (or don't mind including the necessary jar)...

Answer (score 29):

You can also use `URIBuider`

http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html

```
UriBuilder.fromURI(uri).port(port).build("foo", "bar");
```

Comment: +1, a good alternate. I don't think you want to give any arguments to `build` though, not just to update the port which you've already done.

Comment: For Example `UriBuilder.fromUri("page.html").scheme("http").host("localhost").port(80).queryParam("get", "param").fragment("anchor").build()` builds the following uri: _http://localhost:80/page.html?get=param#anchor_

Answer (score 4):

Creating a new URL object from an existing one seems like a simple thing to do:

```
URL originalURL = new URL("http://octopus:345/squid.html");
URL newURL = new URL(originalURL.getProtocol(), originalUrl.getHost(), newPort, originalURL.getFile());
```

Answer (score 0):

here is an another solution that handles common and not well formatted urls. You can enhance it to be more sophisticated.

```
    private static final Pattern URL_PATTERN =
        Pattern.compile("^((?<protocol>.*)(?::\\/\\/))?(?<host>.*?)((?::)(?<port>\\d+))?(?:\\/)(?<path>.*)");
    ...

    public static String replacePortInURL(String urlString, String newPort) {
        if (urlString == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(urlString)) {
            return newPort;
        }
        Matcher matcher = URL_PATTERN.matcher(urlString);
        if (!matcher.find()) {
            return urlString;
        }
        Map<String, String> urlParts = Arrays.stream(new String[] { "protocol", "host", "port", "path" })
            .collect(HashMap::new, (map, partName) -> map.put(partName, matcher.group(partName)), HashMap::putAll);
        urlParts.put("port", newPort);
        return urlParts.get("protocol") == null
            ? String.format("%s:%s/%s", urlParts.get("host"), urlParts.get("port"), urlParts.get("path"))
            : String.format("%s://%s:%s/%s", urlParts.get("protocol"), urlParts.get("host"), urlParts.get("port"), urlParts.get("path"));
    }
```

Comment: You should really keep solutions simple, I think author does not really need such verbose implementation, there are simpler ways to do it like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6490088/14056755

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score -1):

What about using `uri.resolve(URI)`?  Or use `URI.create(URI)`

Comment: Those would both involve string parsing. @Marty would have to first use `toString` to get the string for the current URI, then parse it (which is what the `URI` class is for!) to update the port in the string, then have `URI.resolve` or `URI.create` re-parse the string. Definitely not less complicated, and loses one major benefit of the `URI` class (not having to parse the darned things).